# How to get the most recent posts on Yammer

Tags: api, ms-office, yammer, office365api

I'm trying to query the Yammer API in order to do a search for all the posts with a certain hashtag eg. #win and then return the latest 20 posts.

The problem is, the "https://api.yammer.com/api/v1/search.json" endpoint returns your searches however, they're in seemingly random order and is not the latest.

Yammer limits you to only 20 results each time you call the API, and there may potentially be thousands of posts, so I cannot pull them all down and find the 20 most recent ones myself.

Anyone have any ideas on how to get the latest?

Answer (score 0):

Could you use the autocomplete endpoint to search for the id of the hastag topic and then use the returned id to pull in this documented API? 
https://developer.yammer.com/docs/messagesabout_topicidjson

https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages/about_topic/{{TOPIC_ID}}.json

Comment: I'm getting a 403 error when I try, do you get the same thing?

Comment: Does your user token have access to that particular topic?